# iOS custom splash screen

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, splash-screen

I need to load a bunch of things in the beginning of my application, so I would like to implement a splash screen. I know about the Default.png screen, and I dont think that works.

Does iOS have something built-in for this? If not what is the easiest way to do so?

Comment: Why doesn't `Deafult.png` work for this?

Comment: hope so this link will help you to solve your problem[Check This][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287860/monotouch-loading-screen/13510422#13510422

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your app take too long to load and you want to do your own splash screen manually to avoid being quit by the OS on launch?

Once your app gets control, you throw up whatever you want on screen.  And if that first things happens to be a full screen image view showing your splash screen while lots of things load up, well you can call that a splash screen if you like.

When loading is done, hide or destroy that image view and you are good to go.

I'm not going to provide specific code because, frankly, if you dont know how to show an image view fullscreen, you have some `UIKit` homework to first.

Answer (score 0):

In application did load have a splash screen viewcontroller display till your app is fully loaded then dismiss the controller.  The built in splash screen functionality is Default.png, and a snapshot of the application.